# Crontab command on Ubuntu 20.10 on Raspberry PI400

Tags: cron, raspberrypi

My setup is as follows:

- Raspberry PI: 400
- Ubuntu Desktop 20.10

I changed the operating system on my Raspberry PI 400 to Ubuntu as this give me just a little more flexibility. The only thing i can't seem to get working is `crontab`.

In the old situation the `crontab` command was:

```
30 11 * * * env -i DISPLAY=:0.0 XAUTHORITY=/home/pi/.Xauthority /usr/bin/python3 /home/pi/Documents/Controller_DigitalIQ.py
```

I've tried several commands, but I can't get `crontab` working. Where I am currently at:

```
30 11 * * * env -i DISPLAY=:0.0 XAUTHORITY=/run/user/1000/gdm/Xauthority /usr/bin/python3 /home/steptwo/Documents/Controller_DigitalIQ.py
```

But I don't even know if the `XAUTHORITY` is correct.

All help is appreciated.

Comment: ... well I'd start by adding something like `> /home/steptwo/Documents/crontab.log 2>&1` then you can at least examine the log for errors

Comment: @steeldriver thank you for the logging command. Not adding this feels as a rookie mistake. In the log it showed a python error. Which i'm more equiped to fix. So everything runs perfectly now.